# why no type mismatch error in string split method when run in loop?

Tags: java, string, type-mismatch

I have a string handling related question

```
split() - The return type is String[]
```

In this for loop we are storing the split value in a String literal

```
for (String retval: Str.split("-"))
```

Why doesn't it give a type mismatch error like in the code below?

```
String Str1 = "abfg-hjddh-jdj";
String Str = Str1.split("-");
```

Comment: What does Str point to?

Answer (score 2):

```
String Str = Str1.split("-");
```

gives error because split returns an array, so the correct syntax is:

```
String[] Str = Str1.split("-");
```

In a [`for-each`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop

for (String retval : Str.split("-"))

For each loop `:` indicates you will be iterating an array, collection or list of Strings, so no error is trhown

Examples:

```
for (int retval : string.split("-"))   // error,
```

---

```
ArrayList<Books> books;
for (Book book : books)  // correct
```

---

```
Set<Integer> integers;
for (Integer mInt : integers)  // correct
for (String mInt : integers)  // incorrect!!!
```

**LAST BUT NOT LEAST**: variables in **Java** should start with **`LOWERCASE`**, please check [Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367).